# Matplolib/pyplot: How to avoid rescaling?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm new at Python language and I'd like to put a 2D array with a "true" scale.Let me go with an example...
 The array I'd like to plot has more blocks along the Y axis, than along X axis,but when I plot the axis are rescaled and I see always a square, instead of a rectangle. Do you have any suggestion to fix this?

Here is the code to make the plot:

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
CYZ=np.load('matrix_2013_YZ')
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Coherence matrix Y-Z', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
fig.text(0.45, 0.15, 'year=2013, events=86', color = 'white', visible = True,  fontsize=12, fontweight='bold', linespacing = 2)
ax = fig.gca()
cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', 100)
cs = plt.contourf(CYZ, 20, cmap=cmap, interpolation='bilinear')
ax.set_xlabel('X (km)')
ax.set_ylabel('Z (km)')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.savefig('stack_2013_YZ.eps')
```

And here the plot:
[image: matrixplot]
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ggzh0vgmoi5uh6/stack_2013_YZ.eps?dl=0

Thanks!

Comment: Use the figsize argument of the plt.figure method

Comment: @CatarinaCM what about using `ax.set_aspect('equal')`, it makes the true scale no matter the figure size...